# Angular variable is NaN or undefined

Tags: angular, variables, undefined

I need to get team in my PlayerComponent class. When I use this line of code:

```js
this.teamId = this.player.teamId;
```

I get:

```
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'teamId' of undefined".
```

I use this code in html to retrieve team name from team object.

```html
<p>Team:  {{ team?.name }}</p>
```

Why is this happening? My player loads correctly.

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  player: Player;
  playerId: number;
  team: Team;
  teamId: number;

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService, private teameService: TeamService, private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPlayer();
    this.loadTeam();
  }

  loadPlayer() {
    this.playerId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.playerService.getPlayer(+this.playerId).subscribe((player: Player) => {
      this.player = player;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  loadTeam() {
    this.teamId = this.player.teamId;
    this.teameService.getTeam(+this.teamId).subscribe((team: Team) => {
      this.team = team;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `loadTeam` from the `subscribe` callback of `playerServer.getPlayer`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are loading the team before the player is loaded. Keep in mind that http requests working asynchronously.

To solve your problem you can put the `this.loadTeam()` inside the subscription of the getPlayer() function.

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  player: Player;
  playerId: number;
  team: Team;
  teamId: number;

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService, private teameService: TeamService, private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPlayer();
  }

  loadPlayer() {
    this.playerId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];


this.playerService.getPlayer(+this.playerId).subscribe((player: Player) => {
      this.player = player;
      this.loadTeam();
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  loadTeam() {
    this.teamId = this.player.teamId;

this.teameService.getTeam(+this.teamId).subscribe((team: Team) => {
      this.team = team;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```